# Two slashes in path for the url in ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, url, path

What happens if i give url path like this two slashes `example.com/api//controllername/function`

I am using codeigniter and i have given mistakenly extra slash in the constant defined as API/. I am working in development so there is no errors. Is this a serious problem for production mode. What is the standard way for the url path in ajax server call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) path separator should be single slash.

But even if you add more than two slashes will still works.